# Cannot mount USB drive with ntfs-3g on macOS 11.7

Tags: mount, macports, ntfs-3g, macfuse

I'm trying to mount 1Tb USB drive on BigSur. Always get the same error.

```
sudo ntfs-3g /dev/disk3s1 /VOLUMES/NTFS -volname="test" -o local  -o negative_vncache  -o auto_xattr -o auto_cache  -o noatime  -o windows_names -o user_xattr  -o inherit  -o uid=501 -o gid=20  -o allow_other

fuse: failed to exec mount program: No such file or directory
```

---

```
sw_vers

ProductName:    macOS  
ProductVersion: 11.7  
BuildVersion:   20G817
```

---

```
port installed | grep macfuse

macfuse @4.4.1_0 (active)
```

---

```
port installed | grep ntfs

ntfs-3g @2022.5.17_0 (active)
```

---

```
diskutil list       
  
/dev/disk3 (external, physical):  
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER   
0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk3  
1:               Windows_NTFS ⁨wd1t⁩                    1.0 TB     disk3s1
```

---

```
ls -l /Volumes

total 0  
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   1 Dec  5 18:35 MacHD -> /  
drwxrwxrwx+ 2 root  wheel  64 Dec 30 22:14 test
```

---

```
echo $PATH

/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/iam/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

---

```
which mount

/sbin/mount
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, should've read installation logs.
Run
`sudo ln -fsn /opt/local/Library/Filesystems/macfuse.fs /Library/Filesystems/macfuse.fs`
before first use of fuse/ntfs-3g.
Then OS asks to add security exception, reboots and then ntfs-3g works OK.
PS all name options seem to be ignored as mounted device in Finder is named "macfuse..."